# why this python code results only last results

Tags: python, reverse

I'd like to calculate the matrix satisfying the condition:
`result_x = 1 - initial_x`;
`result_y = initial_y` and
`results_z = initial_y`.
  However, my code results only the last one of each array. Could you please help me out?

```
import numpy as np
import math

def reverse_a_direction(matrix):
    reverse_a = []
    for (x, y, z) in matrix:
        reverse_a = 1 - x, y, z
    return reverse_a

a = np.array([[(0.1666666666666667, 0.8012144614989793, 0.7500000000000000), 
               (0.1666666666666667, 0.1987855385010207, 0.2500000000000000)], 
              [(0.6666666666666666, 0.3012144614989793, 0.7500000000000000), 
               (0.6666666666666666, 0.6987855385010207, 0.2500000000000000)]])

for i in range(0, len(a)):
    print(reverse_a_direction(a[i]))
```

Results of this code:

```
(0.8333333333333333, 0.1987855385010207, 0.25)
(0.3333333333333333, 0.6987855385010207, 0.25)
```

Expected results:

```
[(0.8333333333333333, 0.8012144614989793, 0.75), (0.8333333333333333, 0.1987855385010207, 0.25)],
[(0.3333333333333333, 0.3012144614989793, 0.75), (0.3333333333333333, 0.6987855385010207, 0.25)]
```

Comment: You'll get only the last result, you overwrite the memory.

Answer (score 5):

You are overwriting reverse_a with each iteration. Right solution would be:

```
def reverse_a_direction(matrix):
    reverse_a = []
    for (x, y, z) in matrix:
        a = 1 - x, y, z
        reverse_a.append(a)
    return reverse_a
```

Answer (score 0):

The reversing logic doesn't capture the results but is overwriting and hence you have the last result persisted in `reverse_a[]` variable.

change your assignment from

```
 reverse_a = 1 - x, y, z
```

to

```
 reverse_a.append((1 - x, y, z))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your original array:

```
X = np.array([
    [
        [0.1666666666666667, 0.8012144614989793, 0.7500000000000000],
        [0.1666666666666667, 0.1987855385010207, 0.2500000000000000]
    ], 
    [
        [0.6666666666666666, 0.3012144614989793, 0.7500000000000000],
        [0.6666666666666666, 0.6987855385010207, 0.2500000000000000]
    ]
])
```

You can modify that one axis like this:

```
Y = np.array(X)
Y[:,:,0] = 1 - Y[:,:,0]
```